# Webapp2 and json for datatables

Tags: jquery, python, json, datatable, datatables

I am writing some code so that I can get data from a database using the ajax function on the datatables and I am having a bit of trouble with formatting my dicts so they will look right when converted to json.

What I am trying to do is create a variable with the name `data` that will contain all the rows I need to display for this particular method it is all the items I currently have the code bellow it doesn't work I know this is because of mismatched types and not doing a straight assign. What I am aiming for is like a multi layered array in php that is what I need  `data` to be like I will put an example of formatting bellow my code.

```
data = None

for self.result in self.result.iterator():
    data += { 'Name' : self.result.product, 'Cost' : self.result.cost, 'Keywords' : self.result.keywords, 'ImageID' : self.result.image_id }

    json = {'sEcho' : self.request.POST('sEcho'), 'iTotalRecords' : self.count, 'iTotalDisplayRecords' : self.count, 'aaData' : data }
```

This is the structure example that will work with my datatables I know this because I have done the same thing in php i will show this bellow to further illustrate what I am after in python

```
{'sEcho' : 1, 'iTotalRecords' : 5, 'iTotalDisplayRecords' : 5, 'aaData' : {{'name' : 'one'},{'name' : 'two'},{ 'name' : 'three'}} }
```

PHP working format

```
$this->output = array(
    'sEcho' => 1,
    'iTotalRecords' => 5,
    'iTotalDisplayRecords' => 5,
    'aaData' => array( )
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use list inside the data

```
import json

data = [
    { "name": "john doe", "address": "miami" },
    { "name": "jane doe", "address": "las vegas" },
    ......
]

value = {
    'aaData': data,
    'sEcho': 1,
    ........
}

self.response.write(json.dumps(value))
```

Comment: Thanks mate it was similar but I removed the curly braces round the data and replaced them with square ones and removed the key par setup replaced just with data and then it worked perfectly thanks for helping me along.

Comment: Yes, you're welcome... Anyway it called "list of dictionary" ^^